# How to use poetry to exclude some dependencies when install via `mypackage[core]`?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I want to release a python package to pypi, named it `mypackage` as an example. This package has a lot of dependencies. But for some users that just use parts of the API they can skip some niche and large packages which may take a lot of time to build and install.

I learn that there is a feature named `extras` that allow users to install extra packages by adding a tag in `pip install` command, for example `pip install package[all]`.

But what I am looking for is kind of **opposite** of `extras`. I hope that when a user run `pip install mypackage`, then all dependencies will be installed. But if a user run `pip intall mypackage[core]`, then a minimal dependencies should be installed.

I am using `poetry` but I have no idea how to implement this. It would be appreciated to provide some examples.

Comment: Not possible with extras. This is not a limitation of Poetry but of the Python packaging ecosystem in general. It is something that has been discussed in Python packaging community but no real consensus has been found and implemented. -- Possible alternative is to publish and maintain multiple projects for example `mypackage-core` and `mypackage`.